# Python: Putting the contents of a series of nested lists into a single list

Tags: python, list, recursion

The problem is such:

I have a series of `lists`, always containing two `items`. Each of these `items` can be either a `string` or another list. The goal is to figure out how to make all these `items` from `lists` appear in a single `resultant_list`, and return that `resultant_list`.

My code so far looks like (where nest is the list to be stripped):

```
def strip(nest):
    result_list=[]
    for item in nest:
        if type(item) is str:
            result_list.append(item)
        else:
            return result_list + strip(item)
```

Where am I going wrong here?

Comment: Tell us *how* your code does not work.

Comment: I see now, the return statement is always at the 'end' of the function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you `return` inside your `else` block, then the `for` loop might terminate prematurely and you won't iterate over every element. Wait until the loop ends before returning anything.

```
def strip(nest):
    result_list=[]
    for item in nest:
        if type(item) is str:
            result_list.append(item)
        else:
            result_list.extend(strip(item))
    return result_list
```

Also, this probably doesn't cause a bug in your specific case, but: it's generally preferable to use `isinstance` to test the type of an object instead of `is`. E.g. `if isinstance(item, str):` instead of `if type(item) is str:`

Comment: Or in other words: The problem with OP's code is that he calls `strip` recursively on the first non-string element it sees, but never examines the following elements.